# Adding new separate feature/ module to my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add simple surveys to my rails application. Since surveys are an independent feature, I'd like to 'modularize' it with it's own models, views, controllers. However, I would like a relationship between the 'User' model in my main app and the surveys and survey responses. What is a good way to do this? Modules? Gems? It sounds like basic organization stuff in Rails but I cannot seem to find any pointers. I'd love to see some study links, tutorials or railscasts on this. Thanks.

p.s. I did look at existing gems such as surveyor and they are too advanced for my simple needs and would need customization for views etc. It'll be easier to roll my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Rails Engine is the standard way to separate out a mini-app with an MVC structure of its own.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html or google for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. On first glance it looks right. I'll check it out further and mark your answer as accepted.